# Vector PDF graph become blank after system reinstall

Tags: graphs, illustrator

I used illustrator to create vector graphs and saved them as PDF files and used in latex file. I compiled the .tex file with xelatex (I use MikTeX on Windows 7) and everything was OK. The vector graphs are shown correctly in the final PDF. The code is as follows:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Graphs/Example} % Example.pdf
```

Now, when I reinstalled the system and re-compile the .tex file, everything else was right and there was no errors for the compilation. But all the vector graphs created by illustrator are now shown as blank in the final PDF. Other graphs (.png, .jpg) are still shown correctly in the final PDF.

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

-Richard

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Did you try running `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex`?

Comment: What happens if you open the graphics files themselves using Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys. I figured out the reasons but I just don't know why. Here is what I did:

1. I changed the PDF version from 1.5 to 1.4 when saving from illustrator and everything goes well, all graphs are showing correctly.
2. I do remember everything was fine with including PDF1.5 graphs on my old system. So, I uninstalled MikTeX and reinstalled it. Bing! Everything works flawlessly as before with the PDF1.5 graphs. I don't need to change my graph version from 1.5 to 1.4 one by one. So I was wondering why I reinstalled MikTeX and everything works. The only change I did to MikTeX is changing the default paper size in MikTeX2.9->Mantaince(Admin)->Settings(Admin). To test it, I changed the default paper size from A4(A4size) to letter(lettersize) after reinstall MikTeX and the problem appears again, all PDF1.5 vector graphs are showing blank in final PDF.

So, I found the reasons of my problem, but I just don't know why.